React native(expo) Expo-secure-store getItemAsync returning previous value
I am using react-native expo project which has "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1" Now, after log-in I am storing user details something like this in my function,
 await SecureStore.setItemAsync(
  "user_session",
   JSON.stringify(_user)
   );

And on click of logout, I am using the below code,
await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("user_session");
 navigation.navigate("Signin");

After log-in when I try to get user details using the below code It returns previous user details instead of new user details.
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const setUserFromStorage = async () => {
            let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user_session");
            if (result !== undefined && result !== null) {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                setUser(result);
            }
        }
        setUserFromStorage();
    }, [])


When I log in with one user and log out and log in with another user so on the first time I get the previous user's details and when I kill the app and start again to the dashboard after I get the correct user details.
Thanks in advance!!
